# How can I get my grenades to land where I want?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My Shepard is a soldier and I love lobbing grenades around. I love grenades so much that I make sure my teammates have their grenade skills maxed out too.

However, I feel like I've failed as a Commander, because my teammates seem far more skilled at grenade tossing than me. Their grenades always directly strike their targeted opponent. They don't even seem to need line of sight! Mine usually go sailing over their heads, or bounce off a wall back at me, or any number of other mishaps that I imagine have them questioning why they're not the ones in charge of stopping the reaper invasion.

As Shepard, is there a way I can get my grenades to land where I'm telling them to or to explode upon reaching the target instead of sailing right on by?

Comment: This is actually true for all powers. While squad mates hit their targets directly, Shepards will arc. While this has a learning curve, it's ultimately more versatile as you can learn to bank shots over cover and around corners.

Comment: Use infiltrator. Sticky granades are no easier to hit, but at least they won't bounce back at you. =)

Comment: More specifically, for powers (unless things have changed between 2 and 3), only you need line of site for a squad member to hit their target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aim short, or aim for debris/walls near the enemy so they stop and catch the target in the blast. For what it's worth, I was able to lob grenades with pretty good accuracy directly into the enemy's face by the end of the game but often times it was better to land it at their feet or something that would stop the grenade and catch them and everything with them in the blast.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try aiming your gun in one direction and then throwing your grenade after you're done aiming. That way your grenade will go in the direction that you want it to go :D

Comment: I've tried that, sometimes the grenades still fly high above the enemies.